# Design a round button over two colored layouts

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to design something like that :

[image: What i'm trying to get]

Currently i'm having issue putting the button at "the middle" of the two layouts reunion point. Is there a way i do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe what you need is a [Floating Action Button](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-flat-raised-buttons)

Comment: @DerGolem Adding that is done via using external libraries, right?

Comment: @DerGolem Yeah i thought about floating action button, but they can't be aligned and will stay at the bottom-right (or left) of the screen which is not exactly what i need, but thanks :)

Comment: http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/floating-action-buttons-in-android-l/

Comment: @DerGolem https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ctzWKRlTYHQ

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#FF0000">

        <!-- TO ADD CONTENT HERE -->

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#FFFF00"
        android:weightSum="0.5">

        <!-- TO ADD CONTENT HERE -->

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:text="TEST"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

You can change the layout height from **android:layout_weight="0.5"**

Comment: I know that there are two LinearLayouts in another LinearLayout and that is not a best practice but that was the only way found to use the property android:layout_weight. Cheers hope this is what you wanted

Comment: Unfortunatly, i tried to change the weight of the two LinearLayout, and her's what i get : http://i.imgur.com/4KcJoW7.png :/

Comment: So you want to change the button position when with the layout height? I will check and come with an answer

Comment: In fact, button and layouts won't move or change, but the top layout is 80% of the screen and the bottom one is 20%, as i drew (poorly, i admit :p)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `RelativeLayout` for your parent and try adding two`LinearLayout`s , one below another and set their `height`s, now place a `Button` in your `RelativeLayout` and set `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` for your `Button` .
and if you want to use `weight` for layouts, instead of adding two `LinearLayout` to your `RelativeLayout`, add one `LinearLayout` with `weightSum=100` and then add two `LinearLayout`s to it with custom `weight`s.

for your case , you have to do sth like this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="#f00" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:background="#0f0" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="20" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="test" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have a look on the image... the button is not at the center of the parent.. as the height of layout above is 180 and is 120 for the other one.

Comment: Yep, as @Nitesh said, your solution works but only if both layout have same height, maybe a little tweak will do it, i'm looking at it right now.

Comment: @Nitesh see my updated answer! you can change `weight`s to whatever you want. and if it solved your problem please accept my answer! :)

Comment: Your edited answer is close, but there is a small gap, the button is not aligned, on my screen : http://i.imgur.com/iOPMhwq.png

Comment: add `android:marginTop="-25dp"` to your button for example!