# Android position button in center between 2 layouts

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

[image]

I found this question here too:

[Design a round button over two colored layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021970/design-a-round-button-over-two-colored-layouts)

The first answer there works only if the layouts weight is set to `50%`. The 2nd answer has an drawback. So can anyone of you guys help me with this?

Comment: Refer this one also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921153/how-can-i-position-a-button-in-between-two-layouts

Answer (score 0):

Use LinearLayout with vertical orientation and weightSum = "3" as Parent Layout, then add 3 child in it, Sequence should be

**1) RelativeLayout**

**2) Button**

**3) RelativeLayout**

For 1st RelativeLayout set height to 0dp and weight to 0.4  and for 2nd RelativeLayout set height to 0dp and weight to 0.6

Hope it will help :)

Answer (score 0):

try this in your xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.example.layout.MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bacimage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/nature"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="145dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle2"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle1"
    android:src="@drawable/plus" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="91dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
    />

   </RelativeLayout>
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3wWi.jpg
```